# How to execute "command line"utility after deploying through Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

there is the following code for Capistrano deploy:

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{ release_path }/tmp"
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

I need to execute the "bundle exec sidekiq -d" command after deploy. How can I do it properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably [this](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq) can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can run shell commands in your deploy.rb file.  I usually do something like this below "namespace :deploy do":

```
task :bundle_sidekiq, :roles => :app do
  run "bundle exec sidekiq -d"
end
```

Then, at the end of your deploy.rb file, do the following, where 'foo' can be any task, custom or built-in, to call it:

```
after 'deploy:foo', 'deploy:bundle_sidekiq'
```